# UITableView with pop cannot view data issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am sending my text from a view-1 to another view-2 which has a UITableView. When I push my data I to the other view-2 I can't see the data until I close the application and open it again I can see that data in the table view.

I have used `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` and then reload the the table view but it doesn't work.

More details; A(Add person button with UITableView)-> B(text field with submit button) -> A(Data shown on the table view). This is what I wanna do.

Could anybody help me please?

Here is my full code [My Sample Code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AqveinRStVTcTrWYvzeA0GTUWBEEzr2c2-PlA0NzxWw/edit)

Thanks from now.

Comment: Just inform me if this solves your problem or cause any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen your code and I Found one issue. just put below code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear` method

```
self.dataArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myTxtList"];
self.dateArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDateList"];
```

May this will solve your issue.

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT 1**

Ok the new cause may be as I found with your code is in `submit` method (IBAction).

You create new view controller and just got to the rootview of navigation controller so change the first line of function

```
ViewController *push = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

to

```
viewController *push = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

with the change of above ie my original answer also add the edited answer and see.

May this will solve your problem.

Happy Coding :)

**FINAL EDIT**

I got the issue and have the changes in your code as below

in ViewController.h file
instead of

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dateArray;
```

use

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dateArray;
```

next change is in ViewController.m file
in `viewWillAppear:animated` method instead of

```
self.dataArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myTxtList"];
self.dateArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDateList"];
```

use

```
[self.dataArray setArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myTxtList"]];
[self.dateArray setArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDateList"]];
```

And your application will run as expected with no error or crash.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks Aalok. I have add 'viewWillAppear' but it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: still no row in table view ?? this is crazy. Ok I will try to find out the cause and let you know of the solution.

Comment: Hi i added new changes please apply them and let me know if they are solving your problem or not :)

Comment: Thank you Aalok it works but when I press on add and submit the details I can see the data if I do that one more I got this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'" What could be the problem please? Also I have shred my file so it can help more maybe. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/assbo3uju5go5ku/SavaData.zip

Comment: Also what is the meaning of viewController *push = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; I couldn't understand the (objectAtIndex:0)?

Comment: this is the rootViewController of the UINavigationController.

Comment: Thanks Aalok it works I really appreciate you. I just have small minor problem if I run the application at the first time it doesn't show the data, but if it is already installed in the simulator I can see the data when ever I push data. So what do you think of it doesn't show the data at the first time? You can test it via deleting the application from the simulator and run it again. I have updated my code https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7fid8cvsjdroio7/vIwtCnEqge

Comment: Ok got the issue and resolved it may seem very messy but working

Comment: Just download it from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54106868/SavaData-1%202.zip). My edited code just find Aalok Edit and you will find all my edits

Comment: Thanks Aalok it works now that is so great. Is there anyway so you can help me in explaining the edited code? I hope next time you can see my problem and help me.

Comment: Yes we can chat or can have mail-id of each other for any time chat and any help

Comment: This is my E-mail address luai89ak@gmail.com also if you use gtalk. luai.kalkatawi is my Skype. Please add me :)

Comment: Ok I will sure add you to my Skype my email is aalok@Icreators.in and this is also my Skype, too. So add me too

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[self.navigationController PopViewControllerAnimated: YES];`
May be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as I get on my laptop.

Comment: I have used this code but I have got the same problem which is I have to close the application and open it back to see the data on the table view. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to push your data from one screen to other screen then try:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:push animated:YES];
```

If you want to go back to previous view then below will help you:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you want to go to root view of you navigation controller then try this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use PUSH I always go to another navigation view. More details; A (Add person button with UITableView) Add pressed -> B (text field with submit button) data entered and submit pressed -> A(Data shown on the table view). This is what I wanna do. I hope I could explain what I want.